# Remove empty object from array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects and a delete function that pass the index as a parameter but fails to remove the empty object. Objects containing properties can be removed. Does anyone know how to fix it? The example code is shown below.

```
let array = [
{
  id: '1',
  name: 'sam',
  dateOfBirth: '1998-01-01'
},
{
  id: '2',
  name: 'chris',
  dateOfBirth: '1970-01-01'
},
{
  id: '3',
  name: 'daisy',
  dateOfBirth: '2000-01-01'
},
{}
]

// Objects contain properties can be removed but empty object can not be removed.
const deleteItem = (index) => {
  return array.splice(index, 1);
};
```

Comment: I think your code it's working... just check this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/wp8rezt0/

I'm using chrome on linux and works.

Comment: @FedericoSaenz if you click on show and then remove, it doesn't work.

Comment: Yes, it's works. Only click again on "showResults".

Comment: It's also working for me. Sure that you didn't miscalculate the index?

Comment: OP: what are you actually passing as the "index" argument? Are you expecting it to match "id"? It doesn't: it matches the position in the array (0-based). If you pass 3 it will remove the empty object (as Federico's fiddle shows).

Comment: @FedericoSaenz, I'm using the google chrome browser.

Comment: I got the name wrong, I wanted to ask "sid" what browser he is using, haha. Because he told me it wasn't working for him.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Array.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter out the items which have no properties

```js
let array = [
  {id:"1",name:"sam",dateOfBirth:"1998-01-01"},
  {id:"2",name:"chris",dateOfBirth:"1970-01-01"},
  {id:"3",name:"daisy",dateOfBirth:"2000-01-01"},
  {}
]

const filtered = array.filter(e => Object.keys(e).length)

console.log(filtered)
```

The above works since [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) will return an array of the properties of the object. Getting its `length` property will get the number of items in the array. If the `length` property is `0`, it is coerced to `false` (see: [Falsy values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy)).